# Disassociate, Delete, or both on entity

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

Say I have an entity called account and another entity called contact.  There is a 1 to n relation between account and contact where one account can have any number contacts.

If I want to remove a contact using the CRM SDK can I simply call the [delete method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb928996.aspx) or do I need to remove the relationship first with something like this [IOrganizationService.Disassociate Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iorganizationservice.disassociate.aspx)?

Any examples of this scenario would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you've setup your relationship.  By Default the relationships between Contact and Accounts are Cascade all or Remove Link.  This means that CRM will disassociate the relationship for you if you delete a Contact.  Besides the second SOAP Request, it's not going to hurt anything if you do though.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309412.aspx) for additional information.